# making basic android app, xml help

Tags: android, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/world_series_celebration"
  >

<TextView 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:textSize="36dp" 
android:text="World Series Trivia" 
android:gravity="center"
/>

<Button
android:text="Click to Start"  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="25dp"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

In my program the background shows up fine and so does the text, but the button does not appear.  I feel like i am missing something basic, but i have looked it over and over again and cannot find anything. Any help appreciated

Comment: Can you show the screenshot of ur app?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was you were setting `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` in `TextView`, So it took full screen width just for displaying the `TextView`.

So set `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to wrap up.

Same for the `Button`.

Other things are :

`LinearLayout`'s `android:orientation="horizontal | vertical"`

It will add your components horizontally and vertically when set to horizontal and vertical respectively.

**Modified Code I :** Adding TextView and Button on Single Row...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:background="@drawable/world_series_celebration"
  >

<TextView 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:textSize="36dp" 
android:text="World Series Trivia" 
android:gravity="center"
/>

<Button
android:text="Click to Start"  
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="25dp"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Modified Code II:** Adding TextView and Button Vertically (Adding Components Vertically)...

Change `LinearLayout`'s orientation tag to vertical

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is really needed, but you could try adding `android:orientation="vertical"`
to the LinearLayout